# Can not find the right codes for bind_param

Tags: php, mysqli

The script is part of an login system, this part is to gather all the information about the user.

error codes:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in /home/s010485/domains/jcsl.nl/public_html/medewerkers/includes/main.php on line 28
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? AND mw_gegevens_pass=? AND mw_gegevens_p' at line 6'
>        in /home/s010485/domains/jcsl.nl/public_html/medewerkers/includes/main.php:27
>
> Stack trace: #0 /home/s010485/domains/jcsl.nl/public_html/medewerkers/includes/main.php(27): mysqli->query('?????????SELECT...') #1 /home/s010485/domains/jcsl.nl/public_html/medewerkers/index.php(13): 
>       include_once('/home/s010485/d...') #2 {main} thrown in /home/s010485/domains/jcsl.nl/public_html/medewerkers/includes/main.php on line 27

```
if(isset($_POST['login']))
{
$userpassword = md5($_POST['mw_pass']);

    $mw_gegevens_qry = $connection->query("
                                SELECT
                                        * 
                                FROM 
                                        mw_gegevens
                                WHERE   
                                        mw_gegevens_persnr=?
                                AND     
                                        mw_gegevens_pass=?
                                AND
                                        mw_gegevens_pass!='' 
                                ");
            $mw_gegevens_qry->bind_param('is', $_POST['mw_user'],$userpassword);   
            $mw_gegevens_qry->execute();
            $mw_gegevens_qry->close();
    ($mwgegevens = $mw_gegevens_qry->fetch_assoc());
    if($mw_gegevens_qry->num_rows == 0){
    //wrong inlog
        $error['login'] = "FOUT: Uw combinatie van je personeelsnummer en wachtwoord kon niet worden gevonden. Mogelijk heb je een typefout gemaakt.";
    }
    else
    { 
        set_inlog($mwgegevens);
        if(isset($_GET['pagina']))
        {
        header("location: ?pagina=".$_GET['pagina']);
        }
        else
        {
        header("location: index.php?pagina=home");
        }
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` during development if you're not already doing so.

Comment: I have this on top of my page: ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);, But I will use yours.

Comment: This error message `mysqli->query('?????????SELECT...') #1` has nothing or may not have anything to do with what you posted for code. I suggest you use double quotes instead of single quotes for what's inside that. I.e.: `mysqli->query("SELECT...")` - you need to show us more code.

Comment: With the new error message he gives errors on antoher part of the script. see starting post.

Comment: `mysqli->query` isn't even inside what you added/edited for code.

Comment: I think that error is gone now, thanks to magna, I have a new error now
Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_assoc() in /home/s010485/domains/jcsl.nl/public_html/medewerkers/includes/main.php on line 31

Comment: Another thing. You're using a password storage method (MD5) that is unsafe and is considered "broken". I suggest that you don't spend/waste anymore time in trying to fix this, but to find yourself a piece of code that will be more secure and ready to use, right out of the box.

Comment: The login part is custom made by someone else, I don't understand that part.
I'm searching for some time now for someone to rebuild it. But it is to hard for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as fluffeh pointed out, you need to prepare the statements before binding...

```
$qry = $connection->prepare("UPDATE mw_gegevens SET mw_gegevens_ckey =   ?, mw_gegevens_logintime   =   ? WHERE  mw_gegevens_id =   ?");
echo $connection->error;//displays error
$qry->bind_param('sii', $key,$onlinetijd,$list['mw_gegevens_id']);   
$qry->execute();

$result_set = $qry->get_result();//grab the results

if($result_set->num_rows < 1){

echo "Wrong login";

}

else{
//do something

}
```

incase you want to display something you do

```
 while($row = $result_set->fetch_assoc()){
 //echo row 
 }
```

Comment: Done, I now get this error message:
Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_assoc() in /home/s010485/domains/jcsl.nl/public_html/medewerkers/includes/main.php on line 31

Comment: @Coolen see the edit on how to get the rows returned since the error is coming from `fetch_assoc`

Comment: Thank you for helping, but I think it is better to rewrite the whole login script. It is so full of errors, that is is better to try it again. I can only give 1 person the credits, but next Iyou wll get them.

Comment: Okay no prob. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You need to prepare the statement before using `bind_param`.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO CountryLanguage VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('sssd', $code, $language, $official, $percent);
```

Edit: The code looks good now (though I don't use mysqli, so am not totally familiar with it). As silly as it sounds, are you sure that `$connection` and `$qry` are both successful? It seems that the prepare might be failing due to a non-successful connection and prepare step?

Comment: Thank you very much, I changed the code, but I still get the same error message.

Comment: $qry has not been changed (only the ?) and $connection is good.

Comment: @Coolen Okay, perhaps we should have started with this one... but. If you do away with the prepared statements and manually insert the values into the query, does it run?

Comment: You mean like this $mw_gegevens_qry = $connection->prepare("
        SELECT
          * 
        FROM 
          mw_gegevens
        WHERE  
          mw_gegevens_persnr='.$_POST['mw_user'].'
        AND  
          mw_gegevens_pass='.$userpassword.'
        AND
          mw_gegevens_pass!='' 
        ");

Comment: I meant just to run it super manual like through phpmyadmin or a console with this: `SELECT * FROM mw_gegevens WHERE mw_gegevens_persnr='someName' AND mw_gegevens_pass='thePassword' AND mw_gegevens_pass!='';`

Comment: @Coolen Aren't those error messages saying what is wrong with the query itself? :)